# AppleScript - Add Google Chrome extension programmatically

Tags: javascript, shell, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, applescript

I am trying to **install the Adblock Plus extension for the Google Chrome browser (on a mac - obviously!) through an AppleScript**.
Below is the code I have so far, but it is buggy and unreliable at times because it uses `tell application "System Events" to keystroke ...` if the user is clicking on something else or Chrome changes in terms of how many *'tab clicks'* the desired button is from the default position then the trouble begins and errors are flowing left, right and centre.

```
set abpLink to "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb"
set finalTab to "chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/firstRun.html"

try
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        open location abpLink
        my waitToLoad()
        repeat 3 times
            tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke tab -- Navigate to 'Add to Chrome'
        end repeat
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke return -- Click 'Add to Chrome'
        delay 4 -- This could cause unecessary delays
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
            repeat until exists button 1 of window 1
                delay 0.2
            end repeat
            if exists (button 1 of window 1) then
                click (button 1 of window 1)
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end try
on waitToLoad()
    try
        tell application "Google Chrome" to set chromeLoading to loading of active tab of window 1
        repeat while chromeLoading = true
            delay 1
            activate
            tell application "Google Chrome" to set chromeLoading to loading of active tab of window 1
        end repeat
    end try
end waitToLoad
```

**Is there a better way to accomplish this task (installing ABP for Chrome on mac) that's reliable most-all the time?** Perhaps JavaScript could execute a button click event for all boxes that pop up and require confirmation (currently dealt with by 'tab' then 'return' keystrokes)?

1) On opening `abpLink`, deal with this button:
[image: First button to deal with]

2) After clicking the above button, deal with this one:
[image: Second button to deal with]

Comment: In theory using JavaScript would be better, but you would have to know how to target the button you wanted ... I.e. getElementById()

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, do you have the code to go along with it? I think the elements are all classes but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Just saying couldn't u make a script that downloads or stores the Adblock extension file (crx) and place it in Chromes extension folder?

Comment: @ThrowBackDewd Obviously macOS is never keen to allow AppleScript to manipulate windows without the whole accessibility permissions etc. JavaScript would indeed be the way to go, I believe. Being AS-based, are you able to post a JS function that auto adds the extension that way? Will that embedded JS then bypass the Accessibility Access control so that I don't need to give that permission on ever mac? Thanks.